# How to move the origin to the bottom left, without inverting the axis?

Tags: java

Every solution I've found flips the text/content as well.

Specifically I've tried:
    g2.translate(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
    g2.scale(1,-1);
    m.draw(g2);

Comment: How about getting used to the way Java (and other languages) lay out the axes?

Comment: I need to graph cartesian coordinates.